# NSFW image flag handle time?

Tags: support, flags, moderators

I custom mod flagged a post where the OP had an NSFW image as their profile picture. If I understand correctly this will result in the image being removed by a mod however my flagged still [hasn't been handled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60278817/jquery-datatable-create-rows-from-nested-json-source) 4 hours later?

Doesn't the fact that my flag is about NSFW content mean it will be handled quicker?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208077/discussion-on-question-by-shree-nsfw-image-flag-handle-time).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I custom mod flagged a post where the OP had an NSFW image as their profile picture.

Thank you. This is the appropriate way to handle such cases.

> If I understand correctly this will result in the image being removed by a mod…

Yes, it will, as soon as a moderator reviews your flag, and assuming that the moderator agrees with your assessment.

> …however my flagged still hasn't been handled 4 hours later?

Yes, that's quite normal. A 4-hour lag time for handling a flag is not at all unusual. *Especially* for custom moderator flags, which take the most time of all flags to review.

> Doesn't the fact that my flag is about NSFW content mean it will be handled quicker?

Unfortunately, no. There is no such priority system for flags. All custom moderator flags are placed into the same queue, with no sorting options other than when the flag was first raised. There's no special "NSFW" flag type that will put it at the top of the queue.

It takes a fair amount of time for moderators to process custom flags, as we have to read the flag message, understand it, investigate it, and then take action on it (if appropriate). We also get a *lot* of flags (about 2,000 flags in the past 24 hours). These flags have to be handled by a limited number of moderators, who are all volunteers. This is not our full-time job, and we don't get paid to do it.

---

I have now handled your flag and reverted the profile picture on that account. Sorry for the delay here.